# Cannot find module 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js' when starting express application

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, socket.io

I'm having quite a frustrating issue with something that seems trivial.

I'm running an express application on a node.js server, written in ES6 and compiled using webpack. It compiles without any errors except from the following warning:

```
../node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js 113:11-32
0:0  warning  Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

(although I'm not sure whether this is linked to my current problem)
However, when I start the server I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js'
at Function.webpackEmptyContext [as resolve] (webpack:///../node_modules/socket.io/lib_sync?:2:10)
at resolvePath (webpack:///../node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js?:113:100)
at Server.serveClient (webpack:///../node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js?:116:25)
at new Server (webpack:///../node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js?:53:8)
at Function.Server [as listen] (webpack:///../node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js?:44:41)
at new Socket (webpack:///./server/socket.js?:10:98)
```

Socket class:

```
import io from 'socket.io';

export default class Socket {
    constructor(server) {
        this.io = io.listen(server);

        this.io.on('connection', (socket) => {
            // Handle connection
        });
    }
}
```

The server parameter is the object returned from the `express.listen()` function.

I installed socket.io using the command `npm install socket.io --save`, subsequently adding the dependency `"socket.io": "^2.1.1"` in my package.json, and ran the command `npm install` to update my dependencies but still encounter the error.

As you can tell, I'm rather puzzled by this... especially after following the docs almost exactly [here](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/#Integrating-Socket-IO) so any help is thoroughly appreciated!

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to solve this issue? Thx

Comment: @BillDagg No, I eventually decided to use this instead https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws and haven't looked at socket.io since

Answer (score 20):

This did the trick on my side:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server, { serveClient: false })
```

Comment: Still receiving the same error :( do you have any other ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

package `socket.io` depends on `socket.io-client` (therefore it should be availabe). while the [documentation](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) might explain the problem already (hard to tell, because there is no relevant code).

> Starting with 3.0, express applications have become request handler functions that you pass to `http` or `http Server` instances. You need to pass the `Server` to `socket.io`, and not the express application function. Also make sure to call `.listen` on the `server`, not the `app`.

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(){ /* … */ });
server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've amended my code to create a http server and am passing that object to the socket class now, but I'm still encountering the exact same error. Any ideas? :(

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue finally. I am using nodejs and webpack to build a server running in linux. Using socket.io as a websocket compoent. I get this error and go to see the source code: node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js

```html
Server.prototype.serveClient = function(v){
  if (!arguments.length) return this._serveClient;
  this._serveClient = v;
  var resolvePath = function(file){
    var filepath = path.resolve(__dirname, './../../', file);
    if (exists(filepath)) {
      return filepath;
    }
    return require.resolve(file);
  };
  if (v && !clientSource) {
    clientSource = read(resolvePath( 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js'), 'utf-8');
    try {
      clientSourceMap = read(resolvePath( 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js.map'), 'utf-8');
    } catch(err) {
      debug('could not load sourcemap file');
    }
  }
  return this;
};
```

So , I update my code to disbale client:
var io = require('socket.io')(http, {serveClient:false});

If you would like to use serveClient feature, you may update the code:

```js
Server.prototype.serveClient = function(v){
    if (!arguments.length) return this._serveClient;
    this._serveClient = v;
   var resolvePath = function(file){
    var filepath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), './', file);
    if (exists(filepath)) {
      return filepath;
    }
    return require.resolve(file);
  };
  if (v && !clientSource) {
    clientSource = read(resolvePath( 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js'), 'utf-8');
    try {
      clientSourceMap = read(resolvePath( 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js.map'), 'utf-8');
    } catch(err) {
      debug('could not load sourcemap file');
    }
  }
  return this;
};
```

Then copy socket.io-client folder from node_modules to your webpack build path.
Please notice this a common issue of webpack when there are loading resource using path.resolve instead of require() in 3th part library. Always, similar issue should be handle case by case.

Answer (score 0):

[Webpack's official answer](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/examples/webpack-build-server) is to add `{ serveClient: false }` like people answer here:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server, { serveClient: false })
```